# Working with data from an external data provider (API)

Tags: api, storage

Any advice concerning data management when working with an API? I am wondering whether it is useful to store the data i get from the API in the databank and refresh it every couple of hours or just make a new request to the external data provider everytime the user asks for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually depends upon two factors:

1. First is that how frequent the data is changing at the data provider side.
2. And second is that Does the user wants all the time latest updated data.

If both the cases are true, it would be great if you get the latest data every time and provide them to end user.

If any of the case is false, try to store API data to your databanks and respond user from there. So the whole point is on your business requirements.

Comment: I'm using Google Analytics data to create a cusom dashboard. I don't think it matters too much that the data isn't updated up until the minute.